# asp.net mvc virtual views and web configuration

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor, virtualpathprovider

There are many examples out there which show how to store and retrieve virtual views from a file or database, but none of them show how to configure root web.config so that the application works properly, when a view's content retrieved from a file and contains for instance `@ViewBag.Title = "Some Title"` line.

In this case I get *CS0103: The name 'ViewBag' does not exist in the current context* error, 
just like in cases when I remove web.config from ~/Views project folder.

So, what config elements from the ~/Views/web.config to root web.config in order to fix the mentioned above error?

Is it possible to load config elements into assemby at run time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is related to the fact that in case of a virtual view, a view whose content is retrieved from a file or database, inherits from `System.Web.Mvc.ViewStartPage` that contains Html and Url, but doesn't ViewBag or Ajax properties. The virtual view is referred as follows

```
public class DynamicViewsController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult GetView()
    {
        //SomeModel model = new SomeModel() { Count = 1 };
        return View("/Virtual/VirtualViewToShow.cshtml");
    }
}
```

A view located in ~/Views/ folder inherits from System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage, which has ViewBag and ViewData, and Ajax properties defined.

The workaround to change the action method as follow

```
public PartialViewResult GetView()
{
    //SomeModel model = new SomeModel() { Count = 1 };
    return PartialView("/Virtual/VirtualViewToShow.cshtml");
}
```

and to add

```
  @{
        Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
   }
```

to the text of the virtual view in order to load the layout also.
I don't know the reason why a virtual view inherits from `System.Web.Mvc.ViewStartPage`, but I'll try to find the reason for this in another thread and will post the link when thre thread is created.

**Edited**

So a said the link to the new created thread is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13363273/virtual-view-inheriting-from-system-web-mvc-viewstartpage)

"Show Complete Compilation Source" screenshot attached[image]

Answer (score 0):

Follow as mentioned step and you are done!

- Merge **<configSections>** section of ~/views/web.config with root level web.config
- Now just move **<system.web.webPages.razor>** section from ~/views/web.config to root level web.config
- Cheers :) its done.
- You should also merge **<appSettings>, <system.web> & <system.webServer>** with root level web.config.

Comment: Of course I followed this steps before posting the question, but without success. Are there any additional steps I have to follow? Have it functioned in your case?

Comment: Yes it worked in my case... can you please elaborate your whole scenario?

Comment: The new thread is [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13363273/virtual-view-inheriting-from-system-web-mvc-viewstartpage)