# virtual view inheriting from System.Web.Mvc.ViewStartPage

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, virtualpathprovider

I had an issue with when trying to retrieve virtual views from a file by means of VirtualPathProvider, which is described in [this stackoverflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13209998/asp-net-mvc-virtual-views-and-web-configuration).

Now my question is why does a virtual view inherits from System.Web.Mvc.ViewStartPage, and how to make it to inherit from WebViewPage so that I can use

`ViewResult View(string viewName);`

instead of

`PartialViewResult PartialView(string viewName);`

like in described workaround?

Comment: Have you tried adding the following directive?  @inherits System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage